# How to download a perl file instead of running it

Tags: apache, xampp

I have an anchor in my index.html such this:

```
<a href="example.pl" download>Click here</a>
```

example.pl is located in /opt/lampp/htdocs as well as index.html.
If i run XAMPP and then click the link above, Apache executes the file instead of let the browser download it. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not the appropriate site for questions about configuring your software.

Comment: You have configured your web server to let mod_cgi handle `.pl` files. Remove that directive.